# Why does calling removeAllObjects twice on NSArray cause app to crash?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Using the following code snippet on NSArray one time works but if I call it a second time directly after the app crashes, I don't really understand why, I would have thought that it would blindly remove all objects if any in the array? If thats not true can I test with count > 0 before I run it to be sure the app won't crash or is there a better way?

```
[_transactionRowsRows removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: can you show the crashlog?

Comment: There's something else going on that's not covered by your problem description.  Normally, `removeAllObjects ` works as you thought it should.

Comment: ok i will look at the crashlog in the morning, and post, just left office, its coming to midnight here

Answer (score -1):

NSArray is imutable, you need to use NSMutableArray.

Comment: I assumed that was a typo since calling `removeAllObjects` on `NSArray` should give a compiler error rather than a crash.  Using a cast or something, to get past the compile step should then give an error on the first call rather than the second.